# Multiline MathJax on title

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, titles

With the [recent update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/), MathJax on some titles on the homepage span several lines like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

This makes things a bit tricky to read. Does this happen to anyone else?

Comment: @Xander while they are likely related, it seems this post is about the issue on the *frontpage*. A fuller screenshot of my own: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t65TJ.png Relevant answer on the meta.SE update post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375474/288791

Comment: I noticed something similar in the Review Queues, with an attendant difficulty in parsing titles.

Comment: It looks like the new layout has class `s-post-summary--content-title` set to have `display: inline-block`, which is a shrink-wrap container.  That means MathJax will not know the maximum width that can be used but instead uses the width of the shrunk container and breaks the math accordingly.  If this were changed to `display: block` I think the display would be unaffected, but MathJax would get the correct width and so line breaks would work properly.  If you use the developer tools to change that CSS by hand and then run `MathJax.Hub.Reprocess()` in the console, it works for me.

Comment: This is reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375474/186849). And some seconds ago the following message was posted: "Its a tad hard to test this live, but I believe this has now been fixed. Thanks to @DavideCervone for the assist. We've set the display property of the title link to block as suggested. – Ben Kelly, Staff, Mod"

Comment: @DavideCervone MathJax is again not displaying correctly on the main Activity page (Summary), but it's not clear what has changed.

Comment: @RandomVariable, see [my response](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34510/displays-on-main-question-page?noredirect=1#comment161404_34510) to another related post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should now be fixed. We've set the title link to `display: block` as suggested by @DavideCervone.

Comment: Thank's, it seems to work now.

Comment: This is still an issue on the "Summary" tab of the Activity page.  Titles under "Answers" and "Questions" with MathJax in them often get broken up in strange ways and displayed over multiple lines.