# Displays on main question page

Tags: bug, status-review

The latest changes have certainly messed up MathJax displays on the main question page!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline MathJax on title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/multiline-mathjax-on-title)

Comment: It doesn't answer anything. The cases I just posted are even more egregious than those.

Comment: No need for the snark, it’s an automated message that I can’t really control. My understanding is that both posts are reporting the same bug, in which case one ought to be marked as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: No snark intended. Just frustration. My experience with duplicates in general postings is that we tend only to flag duplicates when there is an actual answer in the original post. But so much flagging goes on these days, I'm definitely out of step with it all. Robjohn is suggesting that I migrate this to meta.SE because he says the problem is not unique to math.SE.

Comment: I completely understand the frustration. Hopefully, the SE devs will fix the issue asap, since it's already been [reported on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375474) and has a status tag attached to it...

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that. So I won't go through the trouble of migrating and reposting my pictures :)

Comment: It looks like the new layout has class `s-post-summary--content-title` set to have `display: inline-block`, which is a shrink-wrap container.  That means MathJax will not know the maximum width that can be used but instead uses the width of the shrunk container and breaks the math accordingly.  If this were changed to `display: block` I think the display would be unaffected, but MathJax would get the correct width and so line breaks would work properly.  If you use the developer tools to change that CSS by hand and then run `MathJax.Hub.Reprocess()` in the console, it works for me.

Comment: @DavideCervone: Thanks! I tried that and the display looks correct. Hopefully the SE devs will implement this soon.

Comment: @robjohn Is there a way for us to modify this ourselves?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I just did what Davide suggested. It only lasts until the page is refreshed. If you are talking about fixing the bug, I think we need to wait until the SE devs change the CSS code.

Comment: According to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375474?noredirect=1#comment1251627_375474) it looks like they have fixed the CSS.  Checking the math.SE home page, it looks like that has done the trick.

Comment: @DavideCervone Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TedShifrin, no problem.

Comment: @DavideCervone: indeed, I have looked at several pages that had this issue, and all look to have the proper `s-post-summary--content-title`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DavideCervone: Oops, I was just pointed to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=1), which, although it has `block` vs `inline-block`, still displays a title wrapped badly (the page number may increase with time).

Comment: @DavideCervone: I don't know if `s-activity-indicator` might be the cause. It has `display:inline-block`

Comment: I should have tried `display:block` before posting. It doesn't fix the display :-(

Comment: The problem also appears on the "Responses" and "Votes" tabs, but I can't post a useful URL.

Comment: @robjohn, it looks like the new design uses a lot of flex-box layout.  I'm not as experienced with that, but it looks like that may be causing the `display:block` to not be full width.  Adding `width:100%` to the `.s-post-summary--content-title` CSS seems to resolve that page.

Comment: @robjohn, it also seems to resolve the problem on the Votes tab.  I don't see a Responses tab, but if the layout is similar, I expect it would still work.

Comment: @DavideCervone: yes, adding `width:100%;` works on both the Votes and Responses tabs!

Comment: @DavideCervone: I see that both Votes and Responses tabs layout MathJax properly, but I don't see `width:100%;` in a place I would expect to see it. Do you know how the layout was fixed?

Comment: @robjohn, whether it works or not without the width CSS depends on how much other text there is other than the math.  If there is only a little bit of text, then the width of that text will end up being the width that MathJax gets for its line breaking width.  So you need to look at entries with some longish math with a small amount of text in order to see the issue.  Or it may be that they have fixed it in another way.

Comment: @DavideCervone: the problem has returned to the reputation page at least. The title for the question that starts "Trig sum:" looks fine on the Activity page, but is wrapped severely on the Reputation page (which has more room). I tried adding `width:100%;` to no effect (after `MathJax.Hub.Reprocess()`).

Comment: @robjohn, it may be that they have changed the layout again.  I checked your activity/Reputation page and saw the item you indicated.  It turns out that the math is not in an item with `.s-post-summary--content-title` class, so changing that won't help.  Unfortunately, there isn't an obvious class to adjust in this case.  Setting `.js-post-expandable-body .d-flex .flex--item.fs-body2 {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}` works for me, but I don't know if that will be appropriate for all cases where these classes are used.  It might be that `.fs-body2` may want to be left off.

Comment: @robjohn, the site designers really are the ones who would have to determine what classes to change, as I don't know how these various classes are being used.  But the flex-box items that could contain math need to be set with `display:block` and `width:100%` in order for the line breaking to work appropriately.

Comment: @DavideCervone: I'm sorry. I should probably just reply to the post of which this was marked a duplicate.  Both are marked [meta-tag:bug] and [meta-tag:status-review], so should get dev attention.